# Silverlight Grid inside of TabItem header

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

My custom TabItem header looks like this:

```xml
<sdk:TabControl>
    <sdk:TabItem >
        <sdk:TabItem.Header>
             <Grid Background="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                     <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <!-- some labels go here -->
             </Grid>
        </sdk:TabItem.Header>
     </sdk:TabItem>
</sdk:TabControl>
```

This creates a single-row, two-column grid inside of the TabItem header. The grid automatically sizes to fit the labels, like it should, but when the size of the actual tab button grows, the grid  does not adjust to fill the space (even though I specifiy `<HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">`).

Why is this? Is there a way to have the grid take up all available horizontal space in the header?

Comment: Normally the tab button grows only as big as its content, is there something you are doing which changes that?

Comment: For instance: When I shrink the browser's width, the tab control begins to stack the tab buttons; and when the tab buttons start stacking, their widths are automatically changed to accommodate the horizontal space. I would like to have the grid stretch horizontally to fill the space, but it's as if no element in TabItem.Header knows about the actual size of the tab button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the default template for a `TabItem` which is used to render the tab places the content of the header in a `ContentControl`.  Now a `ContentControl` has the properties `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` that have the default values of "Left" and "Top".  This is why your grid only occupies the space it needs rather than stretching to the full size available.

In order to avoid this you will need to make a copy of the default template for the `TabItem` and assign the value "Stretch" to both of those properties on the `ContentControl` elements in the template (there are 8 in all, 2 for each possible TabStrip placement (Top, Left, Bottom and Right) ).